# How to "find" your own constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

Say I have a UIView,

```
 class CleverView: UIView
```

In the custom class, I want to do this:

```
func changeWidth() {

  let c = ... find my own layout constraint, for "width"
  c.constant = 70 * Gameinfo.ImportanceOfEnemyFactor
}
```

Similarly I wanna be able to "find" like that, the constraint (or I guess, all constraints, there could be more than one) attached to one of the four edges.

So, to look through all the constraints attached to me, and find any width/height ones, or indeed any relevant to a given (say, "left") edge.

Any ideas?

It's perhaps worth noting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239151/can-you-actually-link-constraints-to-utterly-different-view-controllers)

---

Please, note that (obviously) I am asking how to do this dynamically/programmatically.

(Yes, you can say "link to the constraint" or "use an ID" - the whole point of the QA is how to find them on the fly and work dynamically.)

If you are new to constraints, note that `.constraints` just gives you the ends stored "there".

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622464-constraints

Comment: Can you please, provide full code, what actually you've tried and where is issue. It would be easy for us to check/test.

Comment: why do you need to find it while you could create an `@IBOutlet` easily anytime and can have the direct reference to the constraint.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are really two cases:

1. Constraints regarding a view's size or relations to descendant views are saved in itself
2. Constraints between two views are saved in the views' lowest common ancestor

**To repeat. For constraints which are between two views. iOS does, in fact, always store them in the lowest common ancestor.** Thus, a constraint of a view can always be found by searching all ancestors of the view.

Thus, we need to check the view itself and all its superviews for constraints. One approach could be:

```
extension UIView {

    // retrieves all constraints that mention the view
    func getAllConstraints() -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {

        // array will contain self and all superviews
        var views = [self]

        // get all superviews
        var view = self
        while let superview = view.superview {
            views.append(superview)
            view = superview
        }

        // transform views to constraints and filter only those
        // constraints that include the view itself
        return views.flatMap({ $0.constraints }).filter { constraint in
            return constraint.firstItem as? UIView == self ||
                constraint.secondItem as? UIView == self
        }
    }
}
```

You can apply all kinds of filters after getting all constraints about a view, and I guess that's the most difficult part. Some examples:

```
extension UIView {

    // Example 1: Get all width constraints involving this view
    // We could have multiple constraints involving width, e.g.:
    // - two different width constraints with the exact same value
    // - this view's width equal to another view's width
    // - another view's height equal to this view's width (this view mentioned 2nd)
    func getWidthConstraints() -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        return getAllConstraints().filter( {
            ($0.firstAttribute == .width && $0.firstItem as? UIView == self) ||
            ($0.secondAttribute == .width && $0.secondItem as? UIView == self)
        } )
    }

    // Example 2: Change width constraint(s) of this view to a specific value
    // Make sure that we are looking at an equality constraint (not inequality)
    // and that the constraint is not against another view
    func changeWidth(to value: CGFloat) {

        getAllConstraints().filter( {
            $0.firstAttribute == .width &&
                $0.relation == .equal &&
                $0.secondAttribute == .notAnAttribute
        } ).forEach( {$0.constant = value })
    }

    // Example 3: Change leading constraints only where this view is
    // mentioned first. We could also filter leadingMargin, left, or leftMargin
    func changeLeading(to value: CGFloat) {
        getAllConstraints().filter( {
            $0.firstAttribute == .leading &&
                $0.firstItem as? UIView == self
        }).forEach({$0.constant = value})
    }
}
```

// edit: Enhanced examples and clarified their explanations in comments

Comment: Not really, the answer covers all such cases. To constrain two views (no matter where they reside in the view hierarchy) they MUST have a common ancestor, i.e. be in the same view hierarchy. That's exactly where the constraint ends up to be saved in, by definition. So, it is guaranteed that a view's constraint will either be in itself or one of its ancestors. It cannot reside in a random view of the hierarchy. So it suffices to search the view itself and all ancestors to find all constraints.

Comment: @Fattie Such a constraint would be stored in a superview though. I would consider this question & answer valid only for theory anyway. In reality, you should always keep reference to a constraint if you are planning to change it.

Comment: This also applies to child view controllers. When you add a child view controller to a parent view controller, the child's view becomes part of the parent's view hierarchy as a subview. After you add the child to the parent, you are free to add constraints between any of their views. The rule that these new constraints will end up saved in the lowest common ancestor of the two views involved (not necessarily the parent) applies there as well.

Comment: item two @Sulthan !  I'm amazed you would suggest it is theoretical only, to create views which can "modify their own size".  I've never seen a project which didn't have this!

Comment: @Fattie You can constrain ANY two views, no matter if they are siblings, deep cousins, anything, as long as they are in the same view hierarchy. The constraint itself, though, will end up being saved in the lowest common ancestor of the two, within the `constraints` property of that lowest common ancestor view. I will try to demonstrate using an example soon.

Comment: **"The constraint itself, though, will end up being saved in the lowest common ancestor of the two"** I had UTTERLY NO IDEA ABOUT THAT.  What happens when you move views around !?!?

Comment: @Fattie If you move a view around (that is, you remove a view from its superview), all its constraints to other views are removed. The whole thing is rather simple, really. That's what I meant by constraints being stored in superviews. Look at interface builder. It shows you exactly where every constraint is stored.

Comment: @Fattie It is theoretical only. You are not supposed to search for constraints. If some internal constraint is meant to be changed, it should be exposed. If not, you are not meant to search for it.

Comment: @Fattie Here is an example (probably not the best, but you get the idea) : https://imgur.com/a/GfbB9 Two views D and E not being siblings share same-height and same-width constraints. The constraints reside in view A, their least common ancestor

Comment: @Sulthan I disagree that it is theoretical only. It can be very useful in debugging broken layouts, especially when adding/removing/changing constraints in code.

Comment: hi @stakri, I see your example,   ***I HAD ABSOLUTELY NO IDEA THAT THE CONSTRAINT IS ALWAYS STORED IN THE LOWEST COMMON ANCESTOR.  THAT IS TOTALLY AMAZING.***  You are truly sure that is the case!??? It is ALWAYS the case?!

Comment: @Fattie If "moving" is calling `addSubview` or `removeFromSuperview` then no, it won't move the constraint. It will remove it once the view leaves its current superview.
Even if you want to animate a constraint, you still don't need to search for it dynamically. If you know there is a `width` constraint, you just keep a reference to it. I am writing iOS applications with autolayout about 5 years and I have never needed to search for a constraint at runtime.

Comment: @Fattie yes, it is always the case :) Before iOS 8 introduced the activate(_:) class function, you would need to find the least common ancestor of the two views involved and manually call addConstraint(_:) on it. You can research https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622523-addconstraint to find out more!

Comment: **yes, it is always the case**  That is mindboggling.  I did not have a clue about that fact. @stakri

Comment: Also, removing a view from its superview does not necessarily kill all constraints. It kills constraints that cannot exist anymore. It will not kill the removed view's constrained relations to its subview, for example.

Comment: @Fattie Enjoyed the question and the discussion. Have fun researching about this very interesting topic!

Comment: right on @stakri.  Based on your answer I put in a pretty reliable slab of code in an answer, for anyone who wants a copy and paste solution.  Cheers!

Comment: Brilliant. I deleted my answer because yours answers the question (beautifully) and mine does not. Your answer is my answer upside-down, which is the right way up. :) If we want to know what constraints affect a particular view, we need to start with the view and look upward, as you do. What you've written is something I always intended to write but was too lazy!

Answer (score 9):

I guess you can work with [constraints](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622464-constraints) property of `UIView`. `constraints` basically returns an array of constraint directly assigned to UIView. It will not be able to get you the constraints held by superview such as leading, trailing, top or bottom but width and height constraints are held by View itself. For superview's constraints, you can loop through superview's constraints. Lets say the clever view has these constraints:

[image]

```
class CleverView: UIView {

    func printSuperViewConstriantsCount() {
        var c = 0
        self.superview?.constraints.forEach({ (constraint) in
            guard constraint.secondItem is CleverView || constraint.firstItem is CleverView else {
                return
            }
            c += 1
            print(constraint.firstAttribute.toString())
        })
        print("superview constraints:\(c)")
    }

    func printSelfConstriantsCount() {
        self.constraints.forEach { (constraint) in
            return print(constraint.firstAttribute.toString())
        }
        print("self constraints:\(self.constraints.count)")
    }
}
```

**Output**:

top
leading
trailing
superview constraints:3
height
self constraints:1

Basically, you can look at [NSLayoutConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint) class to get the info out about a particular constraint.

To print the name of constraints, we can use this extension

```
extension NSLayoutAttribute {
    func toString() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .left:
            return "left"
        case .right:
            return "right"
        case .top:
            return "top"
        case .bottom:
            return "bottom"
        case .leading:
            return "leading"
        case .trailing:
            return "trailing"
        case .width:
            return "width"
        case .height:
            return "height"
        case .centerX:
            return "centerX"
        case .centerY:
            return "centerY"
        case .lastBaseline:
            return "lastBaseline"
        case .firstBaseline:
            return "firstBaseline"
        case .leftMargin:
            return "leftMargin"
        case .rightMargin:
            return "rightMargin"
        case .topMargin:
            return "topMargin"
        case .bottomMargin:
            return "bottomMargin"
        case .leadingMargin:
            return "leadingMargin"
        case .trailingMargin:
            return "trailingMargin"
        case .centerXWithinMargins:
            return "centerXWithinMargins"
        case .centerYWithinMargins:
            return "centerYWithinMargins"
        case .notAnAttribute:
            return "notAnAttribute"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's **awesome**, but what about if it's one of the "distance to another view" style??

Comment: @Fattie: edited the answer to include loop through superview constraints.

Answer (score 0):

[`stakri`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47113933/2463616) is OK, but we can do better by using
[`sequence(first:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence(first:next:)):

```
extension UIView {
    var allConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        sequence(first: self, next: \.superview)
            .flatMap(\.constraints)
            .lazy
            .filter { constraint in
                constraint.firstItem as? UIView == self || constraint.secondItem as? UIView == self
            }
    }
}
```

Then, if we check both implementations by [swift-benchmark](https://github.com/google/swift-benchmark) by Google we can see that `Sequence` implementation is much faster (almost +50k iterations for the ±same time).

```
running Find All Constraints: Stakri... done! (1778.86 ms)
running Find All Constraints: Sequence... done! (1875.20 ms)

name                          time        std        iterations
---------------------------------------------------------------
Find All Constraints.Stakri   3756.000 ns ±  96.67 %     291183
Find All Constraints.Sequence 3727.000 ns ± 117.42 %     342261
```

Comment: A fantastic idiom.  But it's worth noting, it is absolutely inconceivable performance could be an issue.  :)

Answer (score -1):

Might save someone some typing.......

Based on stakri's bounty-winning answer, here is exactly how to get

## all constraints of the type "fractional width of another view"

## all constraints of the type "fixed point width"

## all constraints of the type "your x position"

So ..

```
 fileprivate extension UIView {
    func widthAsPointsConstraints()->[NSLayoutConstraint] {}
    func widthAsFractionOfAnotherViewConstraints()->[NSLayoutConstraint] {}
    func xPositionConstraints()->[NSLayoutConstraint]
}
```

Full code below.  Of course, you can do "height" the same way.

So, use them like this...

```
let cc = someView.widthAsFractionOfAnotherViewConstraints()
for c in cc {
   c.changeToNewConstraintWith(multiplier: 0.25)
}
```

or

```
let cc = someView.widthAsPointsConstraints()
for c in cc {
    c.constant = 150.0
}
```

Also, at the bottom I pasted in a simple demo code, example output...

[image]

Here's the code.  V2 ...

```
fileprivate extension UIView { // experimental
    
    func allConstraints()->[NSLayoutConstraint] {
        
        var views = [self]
        var view = self
        while let superview = view.superview {
            
            views.append(superview)
            view = superview
        }
        
        return views.flatMap({ $0.constraints }).filter { constraint in
            return constraint.firstItem as? UIView == self ||
                constraint.secondItem as? UIView == self
        }
    }
    
     func widthAsPointsConstraints()->[NSLayoutConstraint] {

        return self.allConstraints()
         .filter({
            ( $0.firstItem as? UIView == self && $0.secondItem == nil )
         })
         .filter({
            $0.firstAttribute == .width && $0.secondAttribute == .notAnAttribute
         })
    }
    
    func widthAsFractionOfAnotherViewConstraints()->[NSLayoutConstraint] {
        
        func _bothviews(_ c: NSLayoutConstraint)->Bool {
            if c.firstItem == nil { return false }
            if c.secondItem == nil { return false }
            if !c.firstItem!.isKind(of: UIView.self) { return false }
            if !c.secondItem!.isKind(of: UIView.self) { return false }
            return true
        }
        
        func _ab(_ c: NSLayoutConstraint)->Bool {
            return _bothviews(c)
                && c.firstItem as? UIView == self
                && c.secondItem as? UIView != self
                && c.firstAttribute == .width
        }
        
        func _ba(_ c: NSLayoutConstraint)->Bool {
            return _bothviews(c)
                && c.firstItem as? UIView != self
                && c.secondItem as? UIView == self
                && c.secondAttribute == .width
        }
        
        // note that .relation could be anything: and we don't mind that
        
        return self.allConstraints()
            .filter({ _ab($0) || _ba($0) })
    }

     func xPositionConstraints()->[NSLayoutConstraint] {

         return self.allConstraints()
            .filter({
         return $0.firstAttribute == .centerX || $0.secondAttribute == .centerX
         })
    }
}

extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    
    // typical routine to "change" multiplier fraction...
    
    @discardableResult
    func changeToNewConstraintWith(multiplier:CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint {

        //NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self])
        self.isActive = false
        
        let nc = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: firstItem as Any,
            attribute: firstAttribute,
            relatedBy: relation,
            toItem: secondItem,
            attribute: secondAttribute,
            multiplier: multiplier,
            constant: constant)

        nc.priority = priority
        nc.shouldBeArchived = self.shouldBeArchived
        nc.identifier = self.identifier

        //NSLayoutConstraint.activate([nc])
        nc.isActive = true
        return nc
    }
}
```

Just an example demo...

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    _teste()
    
    delay(5) {
        print("changing any 'fraction fo another view' style widths ...\n\n")
        let cc = self.animeHolder.widthAsFractionOfAnotherViewConstraints()
        for c in cc {
            c.changeToNewConstraintWith(multiplier: 0.25)
        }
        self._teste()
    }
    
    delay(10) {
        print("changing any 'points' style widths ...\n\n")
        let cc = self.animeHolder.widthAsPointsConstraints()
        for c in cc {
            c.constant = 150.0
        }
        self._teste()
    }
}

func _teste() {
    
    print("\n---- allConstraints")
    for c in animeHolder.allConstraints() {
        print("\n \(c)")
    }
    print("\n---- widthAsPointsConstraints")
    for c in animeHolder.widthAsPointsConstraints() {
        print("\n \(c)\n \(c.multiplier) \(c.constant)")
    }
    print("\n---- widthAsFractionOfAnotherViewConstraints")
    for c in animeHolder.widthAsFractionOfAnotherViewConstraints() {
        print("\n \(c)\n \(c.multiplier) \(c.constant)")
    }
    print("\n----\n")
}
```

Comment: Just a quick heads-up, I wonder if `fraction fo another view` has a typo. I think it should be "of" or "for".